# Connecting Arduino to the Internet across a firewall proxy

Tags: c++, c, proxy, tcp, arduino

I have an Arduino with an [Ethernet Shield](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield).

How can I connect it to the Internet across a firewall proxy?

For example, the Arduino Ethernet library has only [this](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/ClientConstructor) reference to demonstrate how to connect your board to the Internet but no clue how to do it across firewall proxies, etc.

Repeated from Arduino help pages.

```
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
byte ip[] = { 10, 0, 0, 177 };
byte server[] = { 64, 233, 187, 99 }; // Google

Client client(server, 80);

void setup()
{
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  delay(1000);

  Serial.println("connecting...");

  if (client.connect()) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    client.println("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.0");
    client.println();
  } else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();
    for(;;)
      ;
  }
}
```

As can be seen, there is no way here to resolve my TCP connections across a firewall proxy.

Also I am just curious how this whole process of TCP connection is resolved across a firewall proxy in the above context, please put some suitable reference too.

Comment: I am not sure this belongs on Server Fault.. question goes in too many directions "explain firewalling", "give me sample code", etc

Comment: Edited question for more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Client` class supports neither SOCKS nor HTTP proxies. You'll have to modify the code in `Ethernet.h` yourself.

Comment: Answer is technically correct (existing library doesn't support proxy), however it offers no solution (like the answer with 5 votes up).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to connect through a proxy, use the proxy server name as the adress you're connecting to, and include the server address as part of your GET request:

```
// if you get a connection, report back via serial:
if (client.connect("www.proxy.com", 8080)) {  // This is connecting to the proxy
Serial.println("connected");

// Make a HTTP request through proxy:
client.println("GET http://www.actualserver.com/search?q=arduino HTTP/1.0");
client.println();
```

The original answer is [here](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,158690.0.html).